# How to use xarray's 'where' masking feature with a multidimensional dataset?

Tags: python, dataset, masking, python-xarray

I am looking for a way to use .where to mask data in a 3D array, such that if any of the values within the 2nd and 3rd dimension are true, it returns the entire 2nd and 3rd dimension matrix, instead of only the ones that are true.

I am using xarray with a dataset that contains 200+ variables. Many of these variables are multidimensional arrays. One array in particular has a 110x16x6 shape. I want to mask my dataset so that if any of the 16x6 values are above a certain number, the whole 16x6 matrix at that index is returned.

I have tried using .where with drop=True, but it returns all false values along all 3 dimensions of my data array. I only want values dropped if the entire 16x6 matrix doesn't have any of the values I am looking for.

```
In: DS.cloud_layer_top_level_height.shape

Out: (110, 16, 6)

In: DS.cloud_layer_top_level_height[0]

Out: <xarray.DataArray 'cloud_layer_top_level_height' (Cloud groups: 16, 
Cloud 
Layers: 6)>
array([[2.801278,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan],
      [3.37    ,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan],
      [2.861235,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan],
      [2.981151,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan],
      [2.981151,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan],
      [2.711341,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan],
      [2.861235,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan],
      [2.801278,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan],
      [2.981151,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan],
      [2.981151,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan],
      [2.711341,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan],
      [2.711341,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan],
      [2.711341, 1.362293,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan],
      [2.711341, 1.272357,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan],
      [2.681362,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan],
      [2.681362,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan]],
  dtype=float32)
Dimensions without coordinates: Cloud groups, Cloud Layers
Attributes:
units:        kilometers
format:       F18.9
valid_range:  [-0.5 30. ]

In: DS=DS.where(DS.cloud_layer_top_level_height>3,drop=True)

Out: DS.cloud_layer_top_level_height[0]
<xarray.DataArray 'cloud_layer_top_level_height' (Cloud groups: 16, Cloud      
Layers: 4)>
array([[ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
      [3.37,  nan,  nan,  nan],
      [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
      [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
      [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
      [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
      [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
      [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
      [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
      [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
      [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
      [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
      [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
      [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
      [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
      [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan]], dtype=float32)
Dimensions without coordinates: Cloud groups, Cloud Layers
Attributes:
units:        kilometers
format:       F18.9
valid_range:  [-0.5 30. ]
```

Ideally, since that first index contains one value larger than 3, I would like all of the values inside that matrix to be returned instead of just the single one greater than 3. Also, if a first dimension index contained no values greater than 3 (in the 16x6 matrix), I would like it to be dropped.